# SQL Query to find designation of employee

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables employee and job_role as below. I need to write a SQL query to find designation of each employee by joining this table.

**Input Table**

**1.Employee**

```
   e_id    e_name  Salary       Commission    
    -------------------------------------
    1       ABC     1000        10
    2       CDE     2000        4
    3       GHI     3500        40
    4       JKL     5000        3
    5       MNO     1200        25
    6       XYZ     3000        2
```

**2.Job_role**

```
Designation   Sal_min   Sal_max   Commission_Min   Commission_Max
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Associate      1000      2000       0                   5
Lead           2001      3000       6                   10
Manager        3001      5000       11                  50
```

**Problem**:  **To find designation of each employee based on below logic using SQL Query**

**Logic:**

```
if sal between 1000 and 2000 
    AND Commission between  0 and 5 then Associate

if sal between 2001 and 3000 
    OR Commission between  6 and 10 then Lead

if sal between 3001 and 5000 
    OR Commission between  11 and 50 then Manager
```

**Desired output:**

```
e_id    e_name  Salary  Commision  Designation
----------------------------------------------   
 1      ABC     1000       10      Lead
 2      CDE     2000        4      Associate
 3      GHI     3500       40      Manager
 4      JKL     5000        3      Manager
 5      MNO     1200       25      Manager
 6      XYZ     3000        2      Lead
```

**My Attempt:**

```
select e_id,e_name,salary,commision, 
case when designation='Associate' And commision between Commission_Min   and Commission_Min   
then 'Associate'
else designation end designation
from employee e left outer join job_role
on salary between sal_min and sal_max;
```

**Issue:** How to check AND condition(commission) only for Associate not for other?

Comment: Simply do a `JOIN`.

Comment: What do we get to do your school work :) Please post your current attempt at writing the query

Comment: @jarlh, i tried, but i was unable to check AND condition for Associate and OR condition for other designation in Join condition.

Comment: If you don't show us your code, and any errors'incorrect results, then we can't see and explain what you are doing wrong. You may just need to use parentheses to [control the precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-65B103FE-C00C-46A3-8173-A731DBF62C80), but that can only be a guess...

Comment: I don't see a relation between two tables. On what basis are you joining them? Or, you missed posting something?

Comment: Included my Approach in the post :)

Comment: So what is the point/relevance of the job role table if you have to hard-code the values and logic for the conditions anyway? There isn't anything in the tables to tell you to treat associates any differently to the other roles. It seems slightly more likely you'd want to find all the possible matches (using `or`) and then have some ranking for choosing a role within the matches - maybe on the min or max salary?

Comment: Totally agreed with @AlexPoole! `Job_role` table doesn't make any sense. There is no way you can define cases or add a special case for Associates until and unless you hard code some data in your query.

Comment: Job_role table, we have to maintain the Min and Max value, so that in future, if i need to update value, we don't need to touch Code. We can simply update the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
select e.*,j.Designation from 
employee e
left outer join
Job_role j
on (j.Designation="Associate" and 
(e.Salary between j.Sal_min and j.Sal_max) and (e.Commission between j.Commission_Min and j.Commission_Max)) 
or(j.Designation not in("Associate") and 
((e.Salary between j.Sal_min and j.Sal_max) or (e.Commission between j.Commission_Min and j.Commission_Max)))
order by e.e_id ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Query. it's working fine, except in 1 scenario , where salary=2500 and commission =25, 
so in this case i am getting both designation (Lead and Manager). but i was expecting 'Lead' only . since he mapped to lead first, it should not check for next condition.

Comment: Thanks again for your approach :)